# Angular Material ng-click not working in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a directive to create a header page for my html page, since the header will appear on multiple pages.
I created a directive called 'header' which simply loads header.html

This is the html that uses the directive

This is the directive

```
   app.directive('header', function() {
    return {
        controller: headerController,
        templateUrl: 'header.html'
    };
});
```

header.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
<script src="scripts/signIn/signIn.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/signIn/signInController.js"></script>

<md-button class="md-button" id="accountCreation" ng-click="showLogInPage()">Create Account/Login</md-button>
```

My header.html file has a button that should open a dialog but it isn't working. I previously created the header using javascript and this worked fine. showLoginPage is defined in the controller as $scope.showLoginPage() but that function isn't being called upon clicking the button

A snippet of my controller

```
app.controller('headerController' , function($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia,userService) {

$scope.status = '  ';
$scope.userService = userService;
var useFullScreen = ($mdMedia('sm') || $mdMedia('xs'))  && $scope.customFullscreen;
$scope.showLoginPage = function() {
...
}
});
```

Comment: can't load scripts using angular templates, include them in the main page

Comment: Check the capitilization -- `ng-click="showLogInPage()"` vs `$scope.showLoginPage = function() {`

Comment: can you try moving your controller function into your directive definition, instead of separate file? 
I think your controller was not registered into your module when your directive was initialized.

Comment: Also you need quotes on the controller name -- `controller: 'headerController',`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
I was able to figure this issue out. Adding the quotes was one thing. I also had to create the controller in header.html as well.